# How to create ui components with background arts. Examples given

Tags: css, user-interface, graphics, background-image

I love web designing and want to learn more about it. I have come across ui components that has background arts to them and they look more nicer than a normal white background. What are the tools needed to create these backgrounds and what's the process to do this. I have attached some examples to show you what i'm talking about.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It might be as easy as assigning an SVG file as a `background-image`.  Try it.

Comment: @PeterO. what tools can you recommend to create background images like the ones i have posted?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a ... tool ... are off topic for Stack Overflow..."  In any case, questions on designing graphics like the ones you posted are likewise off-topic.